# Autenticação PHP x Proxy

Tags: php, proxy, ad

Possuo uma rede com autenticação proxy a qual não tenho acesso as configurações e um sistema na rede interna via PHP.

Os usuários e senhas do sistema PHP são os mesmos do AD e PROXY, porém gostaria que ao enviar uma requisição em PHP este mesmo fosse autenticado no proxy externo.

Foram testadas algumas configurações com o NTLMAPS, porém só não autenticou o PHP e ficou lento em outras formas de requisição.

Alguém conhece alguma alternativa?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar classes como o PHP LDAP? http://sourceforge.net/projects/adldap/

Comment: ainda não tem algum exemplo prático ?

Comment: Dentro do zip possui uma pasta examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando este post:

http://www.learncomputer.com/php-ldap/

Utilizando funções nativas do php para LDAP

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php